# Holographic dualities and strong subbadditivity of entanglement entropy

Tags: statistical-mechanics, quantum-information, entropy, ads-cft, holographic-principle

[Recent analysis](https://arxiv.org/abs/1412.3514v1) of inequalities satisfied by entanglement entropy in AdS bulk duals have led to establishing an equivalence between Strong Subadditivity and the Null Energy Condition (NEC)

How hard would be to prove a similar result for dS spaces? Assuming of course that the equivalence holds in theories with dS bulks